# Shifting a button by some pixels when on click & hold

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Discord web app, when clicking & holding on a navbar (Server) button, it shifts a little bit down as shown in this GIF : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYerL.jpg

How can I achieve this effect in CSS, or maybe CSS & JS?

Comment: [`:active` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: @Spectric I understand, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo `:active` and position `absolute`

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #ccc;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.btn:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">press me</button>
```

or use `:active` with `translateY()`